# Draw complete graph with vertices placed at random positions?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How can I draw a complete graph on $N$ vertices, such that the vertices are placed randomly on the plane?

Comment: Something like `CompleteGraph[5, VertexCoordinates -> RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {5, 2}]]`?

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Perfect, thanks. You can post an answer if you like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the pattern syntax for setting properties then you will not need to repeat the number of vertices in your code.

```
CompleteGraph[10, VertexCoordinates -> {_ :> RandomReal[1, 2]}]
```

Comment: That's quite a bit nicer!